# Making substring/text bold without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React - useEffect and Regex. Why it does not work outside UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

This is my first post on Stackoverflow!.

Saw many posts which suggested to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML for making substring/text bold. Just discovered and stumbled upon a new way to achieve this where we can replace the substring to be bolded or where html has to applied by putting the substring inside a holder character/substring like * text to be bolded* and then replacing * * with the html tags by taking the inner html. (idea came from how Whatsapp :) uses this technique in chat )

The twist is putting the replace logic  in useEffect so that when component renders, * * is replaced by <strong></strong> and then setting back the inner html. Any html tags in original text will not be converted as they will be encoded to &lt &gt and will not effect the render and stays as it is.

Here is the code using useEffect.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const useAutoBoldText = () => {
  //convert * * to <strong><i></i></strong>
  //when the component mounts
  //&lt; &gt; stays as it is
  useEffect(() => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".auto-bold");
    elements.forEach((element) => {
      let htmlContent = element.innerHTML;
      console.log("Before : " + element.innerHTML);
      const boldSyntax = /\*(.*?)\*/g; //replace regex as you wish if you use other * *
      htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(
        boldSyntax,
        "<strong><i>$1</i></strong>" //play with html tags here
      );
      element.innerHTML = htmlContent;
      console.log("-----------------");
      console.log("After : " + element.innerHTML);
    });
  });
};

export default function App() {
  //text within * * gets rendered to html
  //html tags in text doesn't get rendered since they are encoded to &lt; &gt;
  const string1 = "Hello *CodeSandbox* <b>This doesn't get bold</b>";
  useAutoBoldText();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p className="auto-bold">{string1}</p>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/hyrcxg?view=Editor+%2B+Preview&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

I added the replace logic in script tag but didn't work though. Why? Atleast once when DOM content is loaded it should have worked right?
Does using useEffect and regex approach look safer way than dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

```
<script>
//Didn't work
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.auto-bold');

    elements.forEach(element => {
      let htmlContent = element.innerHTML;
      const boldSyntax = /\*(.*?)\*/g;
      htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(boldSyntax, '<strong>$1</strong>');
      element.innerHTML = htmlContent;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Open to any suggestions/questions from the community :)

Comment: Here is the output of console :

Before : Hello \*CodeSandbox\* &lt;b&gt;This doesn't get bold&lt;/b&gt;
 -----------------
After : Hello <strong><i>CodeSandbox</i></strong> &lt;b&gt;This doesn't get bold&lt;/b&gt;